# mod_rewrite not works with http:// but not http://www

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code:

```
####  Redirect to www location

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sspconf.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sspconf.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

When I type in http://sspconf.com/ it re-directs to https://www.sspconf.com/ which is fine.

However if I type http://www.sspconf.com/ (with a www) it doesn't re-direct. Can someone help?

Comment: Is this the only rule in your .htaccess or you have more? Are you using some PHP/CMS framework?

Answer (score 0):

Change your rule to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sspconf.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sspconf.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

So that it redirects if it is missing the "www" *OR* if it isn't HTTPS.

Comment: This may not be quite what OP wants. What if another domain is requested, like `blog.sspconf.com`?

Comment: Sadly this gives me an infinite loop.

Comment: There will be no need for a blog.

Comment: @AndyWebb are you sure there isn't something else redirecting (other rules, php code, etc)? Those rules work for me and there is no infinite loop.

Comment: @Jon Lin - I've tried twice, the website itself is simple and there is no other .htaccess re-directs or php redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

and change this line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sspconf.com [NC]
```

to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sspconf.com [NC]
```

The `^` only matches the start of the string, so `www.sspconf.com` is a non-match.

So, your overall rule will look like this:

```
####  Redirect to www location

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sspconf.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sspconf.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

*Edited to address comment*

Comment: Sadly this gives me an infinite loop.

Comment: Unless I'm going mad, still a loop.

Comment: I cannot test this now, but I think the logic above is correct. You very likely have an issue with the `R=301`; try clearing your cache. (It's safer to use `302` redirects while testing because `301` is *supposed* to be permanent, so your browser will usually stop trying the original URL, cutting out mod_rewrite entirely.)

Answer (score 0):

The following has solved my problem, thanks for the help.

```
# Force SSL on entire site

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sspconf.com/$1 [R,L]
```